# Next.js+Redux authentication and redirect

Tags: react-redux, next.js, redux-thunk

I'm starting to build a next.js application and i'm using redux. 
I read a lot about authentication in next.js and specifically with redux.
Let's say I have a /login page and a /private page.
And my redux store contains isAuthenticated state.
So, as i see it, i need to think of the following scenarios:

1. When navigating to /private through the address bar (SSR) , i should redirect to /login.
2. When already in /private and the isAuthenticated changed to false.
3. After logging in successfully in /login, update isAuthenticated state and redirect to /private page.

Did i miss some important possible scenario (UX and security wise)?

Regarding those cases, I have a few questions for the experts here:

1. For scenario number 1, i implemented an authentication check in getinitialprops (only when ctx.req is not null). If the user is not authenticated, i redirect him with 302 response to the /login page. Is that ok?
2. About scenario number 2, where should i implement this logic? What is the best practice? I can think of  implement the check in getinitialprops, in render() function, in componentDidUpdate...
3. Should i redirect after calling the redux action (authenticate), or in the redux action?
4. Should i fire the login request from within the redux action or in the handle function in component, and on success call the redux action.
5. When redirecting, should i use Router.push or Router.replace?

Please help me to understand the best practice once and for all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is based on experience:

1. For scenario number 1, i implemented an authentication check in getinitialprops (only when ctx.req is not null). If the user is not authenticated, i redirect him with 302 response to the /login page. Is that ok?

**Yes, this is okay. It does what it needs to do.**

2. About scenario number 2, where should i implement this logic? What is the best practice? I can think of implement the check in getinitialprops, in render() function, in componentDidUpdate...

**Definitely getInitialProps. What we did is we made a helper that can be used by both SSR and CSR components. What the helper does is it accesses the Cookies for both instances, that way, the auth state is consistent. There could be better ways but this is how we implemented it.**

3. Should i redirect after calling the redux action (authenticate), or in the redux action?

**Depends on your team's protocol. For us, all side effects such as redirections, are allowed to be done inside the Redux Sagas.**

4. Should i fire the login request from within the redux action or in the handle function in component, and on success call the redux action.

**I would suggest using Sagas as it is much more cleaner and gives you another layer to keep all your sideeffects in. But in your case, I would suggest keeping the actions clean and just do what it needs to do: change the state.**

5. When redirecting, should i use Router.push or Router.replace?

**I would suggest `Router.push`. Using replace would overwrite the top of the route stack and that may lead to undesirable effects when hitting back or what not. This would depend on your requirements should it be concerned about what happens when you hit back.**

Don't overcomplicate things. Make it work and find better ways to do it after you actually make things work.

Comment: Thank you Edrian for your detailed comment!
Regarding your answer to 2:
1) the getInitialProps will run when the state is changed?
2) For security reason my cookie (JWT) is not accessible from JS (HttpOnly). what i did is that for every request to the server it checks the JWT and update the redux store. that's server-side. but for client side, i can't check in the HOC that cookie is present, can i check the Redux store's state for isAuthenticated? or should i add one more (unsecured) cookie for client side help? i really dont know.
I will definitely will investigate about redux saga now...

Comment: BTW i'm using redux-thunk. you think i should move to redux-saga?

Comment: To answer your questions: 1) No, getInitialProps will only run on initial load of the Page. 2) If you REALLY need to be that strict, then from what I see, you would need to do a call your server to check if you are authenticated or not, which would be a pain. But if not, exposing your cookie to your client will make things easier. Like I said, don't overcomplicate things. Do what works.

For the question of moving to redux-saga from thunk, I dont think you should move to Saga because, in a way, they address the same concerns. Just different implementations.

Comment: Regarding 2, why not just checking store state for isAuthenticated? I update the store in the server requests. So if client asks /private and he is not authenticated, it will get 302 redirect to /login. That is security wise (for every request that needs protection i check if client is authenticated). UX wise, i used useEffect hook (in every page) and there i check the redux state, if it doesn't fit, redirect the user. As i see it, if the user is not trying strange things, the redirection in the useEffect will happen only when redux state changes (e.g. user logged out). It is not for security.

Comment: I see. This is the case for our application because the authentication that we made is built around cookies. In a way, it's more of a preference than a specific method of authentication. Whatever works would do. If your current setup works for you then that's fine. We just find it easier for everyone if we used cookies as the single source of truth when it comes to authentication.

Comment: You are not afraid of XSS attacks in your app? When cookie is not HttpOnly, an attacker can steal the user cookie with XSS attack.

Comment: Nope. We are sanitising all possible inputs, regardless if its from the query or body, in the API.